# Request success in Elastic beanstalk but getting 404 in ec2 aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, gradle, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a simple project in aws. Request is successfull in elastic beanstalk, But i want to deploy it in ec2,where am getting 404 for same war file.

Can anyone please help me to resolve it,

**Java and tomcat versions are same in compiled and deployed version i.e java 8 and tomcat 8.5**

**GradleDemoApplication.java**

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class GradleDemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer  
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GradleDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    }
```

**TestController**

```
@RestController
public class Test {

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test() {
    return "success";
}
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/gradle
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
server.port=8080
```

**index.jsp**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Spring boot --Gradle</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: can you access the page using `localhost:8080` from the instance? If yes, what is security group looks like?

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran  thank you for your response.yes i can access localhost:8080, tomcat is running succesfully. only my requests doesnot work. I have edited my question with img of security group. Please do check it

Comment: can you run these and post the results? `curl -vvv <ip>:8080` and `telnet <ip> 8080` for windows 
or `nc -v -z <ip> 8080` for linux

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran Connection to <ip> 8080 port [tcp/webcache] succeeded!

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran * Connection #0 to host ip left intact, telnet : Connected to ip